# Matrix similar to a permutation matrix over $Z$

Tags: matrices, permutations

Suppose we have $m\times m$ matrices $B,C$ with integer entries such that:
$$A^{-1}BA=C.$$
for some matrix $A$ with integer entries. ($A^{-1}$ may not have integer entries). Now, suppose we also know that $C$ is a permutation matrix and that $det(A)$ is co-prime to the order of $C$ (as a permutation). Then, does there necessarily exist $A'\in GL_m(\mathbb{Z})$, so that:
$$A'^{-1}BA'=C?$$
This question has its roots in the representation theory of finite groups. I know that the above isn't true if we remove the condition that $C$ is a permutation matrix. For a counterexample, see [this](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-diagonalizable-matrix-over-q-but-not-over-z/). Does having this extra condition change the answer?

Comment: I guess you also want $A\ne 0$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Yup! Edited.